# Symfony 2 Self referencing many to many repository

Tags: mysql, database, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a self referencing many to many relationship on my User entity being they can have many followers or follow many other users.

I am now trying to write a query in the user repository which will determine if a user is following another user.

I tried to write the query directy on user_relations (the mapping table) but it would not let me as it not related to the user entity.

So I tried:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->select('count(u.id)')
            ->innerJoin('u.following', 'r')
            ->where('u.id = :userID')
            ->where('r.from_id = :followingID')
            ->setParameter('userID', $userId)
            ->setParameter('followingID', $followingId)
```

Which results in an error stating the user entity does not have a field named from_uid.

How the hell can I correctly achieve this?

Comment: `r.from_id` is a mapping `User::$from_id`. Guessing 'r' is a User entity, try something like `r.id`? I'm just assuming, because your User entity isn't added to your question.

Comment: ah like you say r.id was correct, as its no looking at the mapping table user_relations, like I thought it was, its looking at another user entity. I keep trying to use doctrine language like it using the tables rather than the entities.

Comment: :) but it's not... It's object-relational ;) If you define a relationship, most of the time an instance of `targetEntity` is at the other side. Or a collection / array containing instances of them. Or just `null`. Try keeping that in mind when you're getting errors like that ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MEMBER OF` doctrine keyword

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u.id FROM User u WHERE :followingID MEMBER OF u.following'); 
$query->setParameter('followingID', $followingId); 
$ids = $query->getResult();
```